# Why the discrepancy between zone.utc_offset and zone.now.utc_offset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

In rails console:

```
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Samoa'].utc_offset
=> -39600
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Samoa'].now.utc_offset
=> 50400
```

I'd expect to see a discrepancy based on DST, perhaps, of an hour.
Why the huge difference here?

---

UPDATE:
`Samoa` is the only timezone with this behaviour. It's easy to find:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone
  .all
  .select{|tz| (tz.now.utc_offset - tz.utc_offset).abs/(3600) > 1}
```

Comment: That's interesting. What do you get when you do `p ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Samoa'].now`?

Comment: @jordan `now` is different every second I run it! OMG!! :p But seriously, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean type `p ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Samoa'].now` in your console. What does it print?

Comment: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 17:53:28 WSDT +14:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Samoa time zone moved across the International Date Line at the end of December 29 2011.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa_Time_Zone

So the zone.utc_offset value is for pre December 29 2011 values, and any time after that the utc_offset is adjusted appropriately.

```
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Samoa'].parse('2011-01-01').utc_offset
-36000
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Samoa'].parse('2015-01-01').utc_offset
50400
```

Comment: Yes, but other many other time zones have base offset changes throughout history,  so why is Samoa the only one (according to the OP) that is like this?  What date is used to determine the offset when you don't provide one?

Comment: I am the op. I answered my own question. I think it's because it moved over the IDL very recently. The date to provide the offset might have been set when the rails library was originally developed (pre 2012).

Comment: Lol, I didn't catch that! :D   Thanks.   I think you are right - the initial date must be something relatively recent, like 2010.